# How to load article/s from a different page e.g. `articles.php` to another page i.e. `index.html`

Tags: html

If I wanted a section on my homepage to be devoted as teaser to an article on a different page would the following markup be correct?

```
    <section>
      <article>
        <a href="">
          <img src="" alt="">
          <h1></h1>
          <p></p>
        </a>
      </article>
    </section>
```

Comment: What do you mean by teaser? Please elaborate. Your question is ambiguous to me. Or you mean you want to include an article page to your homepage?

Comment: I want to create a section on my home page that has an excerpt of an article that links to the full article on a different page.

Comment: Refer to my answer below and see if it would work for you

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume this is your home page `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HOME PAGE</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#list").addClass('loader');
    $("#list").load('article.php', function() {
        $("#list").removeClass('loader');
    });

});

</script> 
<style>
.loader{
    background-image:url(loader.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    height:10px;
}
</style>

<!--and this is where you want the articles to appear-->
<div id="list"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is your article page: `article.php`

```
<section>
      <article>
        <a href="">
          <img src="" alt="">
          <h1>Heading</h1>
          <p>article</p>
        </a>
      </article>
</section>
```

And if the article is on a specific `<div>` or `<article>`. then give that `<div>` or `<article>` an ID e.g.  `<div id="divID" >`  or `<article id="divID" >`and use this javascript load code instead

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#list").addClass('loader');
        $("#list").load('article.php #divID', function() {
            $("#list").removeClass('loader');
        });

    });

</script>
```